# overload operator as generic function

Tags: swift, generics

i saw an example on "Pro swift" book.

it overloaded the operator, the first parameter "lhs" is a function that takes T -> U.

but "generateRandomNumber" function is Int -> Int

How can it work on >>> operator?

how does it work?

thanks.

```
import Foundation
infix operator >>> { associativity left }
func >>> <T, U, V>(lhs: T -> U, rhs: U -> V) -> T -> V { 
    return { rhs(lhs($0)) }
}

func generateRandomNumber(max: Int) -> Int {
    let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max)))
    print("Using number: \(number)")
    return number
}
func calculateFactors(number: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (1...number).filter { number % $0 == 0 }
}
func reduceToString(numbers: [Int]) -> String {
    return numbers.reduce("Factors: ") { $0 + String($1) + " " }
}

let combined = generateRandomNumber >>> calculateFactors >>>
reduceToString
print(combined(100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the documentation about generics.

```
let combined = generateRandomNumber >>> calculateFactors >>> reduceToString
print(generateRandomNumber.dynamicType)
print(calculateFactors.dynamicType)
print(reduceToString.dynamicType)
print(combined.dynamicType)
/*
 Int -> Int
 Int -> Array<Int>
 Array<Int> -> String
 Int -> String
 */
```

Comment: i know this. but the generic operator function takes the argument on the left is T -> U. but generateRandomNumber is Int -> Int, can't be the same type.

Comment: can you explain more? any example? when i tried to make a generic function return the same type. it popped up error. "cannot convert return expression of type 'T' to return type 'U'"

Comment: @user3762515 When writing a generic functions with, say, two generic types, `T` and `U`, these may, when used in practice, be the same or may differ. The compiler will have to assume however, that they are not the same, hence not allowing to return (in the generic function) a value of type `T` when one of type `U` is expected. By following these rules, the compiler ensures type safety. When calling such a generic function, we may, however, naturally choose to use the same types for `T` and `U`, e.g. `Int` in the example in your question

Comment: @user3762515 ... If you know, on the other hand, that in your generic function, `T` and `U` were always the same, then naturally you wouldn't need to use two generic types, but could simply use a single one, e.g. `T`.